# Republish http cloudpages to keep existing ID and introduce SSL

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, ssl

We started to use cloudpages before SSL was configured. Since now it's available we would like to republish the pages we have in place but under https. Is there any opportunity to do it in a way that will allow us to keep existing pages IDs (not to changes other assets referencing these cloudpages)

Answer (score 5):

When setting up the SSL, normaly the support will ask you some questions amongst which are the questions:

> Will you require references made directly to HTTP to be force
>   redirected to HTTPS?
>
> ...OR...
>
> Would you like for references made directly to HTTP to work as is,
>   without redirecting to a secured link?

You simply need to answer **YES** the **first question** and **NO** the **second one**.

PS: you may need to take in consideration this support's recommendation:

> If you elect to enable the Forced Redirect feature, we recommend that
>   you consult with your IT/Development teams beforehand to ensure your
>   current landing pages and/or link references are equipped to properly
>   resolve in the event of a redirect to HTTPS (ie - mixed content
>   errors, hard coded HTTP, etc).